# Summary of task data in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of tasks in the following format in Excel:

```
Task             Start         End
First Task       22/09/2016    04/11/2016
Second Task      18/11/2016    30/01/2017
Third Task       04/01/2017    28/03/2017
```

I'd like to produce a month summary like this:

```
Sep-16  Oct-16  Nov-16  Dec-16  Jan-17  Feb-17  Mar-17
1       1       2       1       2       1       1
```

Basically this is showing the number of active tasks in a month. I've tried lot's of combinations of COUNTIFS but can't seem to get this to work.

Any help would be greatly appeciated!

Thanks,

M

Comment: "I've tried lot's of combinations of COUNTIFS but can't seem to get this to work." Then you would not mind showing one that you've tried at the very least

Comment: How can we help if you don't even specify what we are counting? When a task starts? when it ends? when the entire job starts? when the entire job ends? Be specific within your question, it will help to get the answer you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the months have been entered in (say) E1:K1, check that the start date is on or before the end of the month and finish date on or after the beginning of the month:-

```
=COUNTIFS($B2:$B4,"<="&EOMONTH(E1,0),$C2:$C4,">="&E1)
```

entered in E2 and pulled across.

[image]

Comment: Hi Tom - thank you so much, this worked perfectly! Much appreciated!